# What are the key differences between .net 4 and .net 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

What are the key differences between .net 4 and .net 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this :

http://saimaterial.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/key-features-of-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-and-net-40/

Answer (score 4):

[Read this huge list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Named arguments and optional parameters is a nice one.